# Restrictions to foldernames when acessing servers by webdav?

Tags: webdav

Hy,

Accessing my file server using webdav works fine for folders with a short name (eg. fotografie).  Eventually I can not acces the folders with longer names or containing characters such as "-" or containing capitals.

Please your suggestions

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be rather Windows oriented.

It is likely you got bitten by the maximum path length since WebDav has some serious limitations...

Avoid using any special characters and spaces in file and/or folder names. Webdav uses HTTP/HTTPS so any special characters and spaces need to be URL encoded adding to the maximum length available. That would be `&%#+? *'"></\|:` (I might have missed a few ;) ). Those will take up 3 positions as they are processed as `%nn`; `%20` is a space.

The total path length and file length is in theory 256 characters but that excludes UNC prefixes and Webdav prefix; [Office](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-office_install/unable-to-open-excelxls-files-with-very-long/290c6e39-929a-4788-95c4-d3364a7060f7) for instance only allows 218 chars from Windows itself; so not even from Webdav.

190, 200 characters is probably the maximum limit for path and filename.